# Intermittant Touchpad Driver

Tags: windows-10, laptop, drivers, touchpad

I'm having trouble with touchpad drivers that are intermittently failing, and would appreciate further steps for troubleshooting. I've searched for help on Acer forums, but they've failed to provide a solution beyond the usual "try rebooting". I'm running Windows 10 on an Acer Nitro 5 AN515-57 laptop. Here's a basic description of the problem:

- Every few sleep/awakening cycles, my touchpad driver stops working. The device manager menu goes from this:

[image: touchpadOK]

- To this:

[image: touchpadBad]

- The device properties for the stopped I2C HID Device gives the following info:

[image: deviceProperties]

What I've tried:

- Rebooting: this doesn't work
- Removing the offending driver through device manager, then reinstalling the default driver using the "Scan for Hardware Changes" option: this works most of the time (~80%)
- Removing the offending driver, then reinstalling more recent Elantech or Synaptics touchpad driver: this works sometimes (~10%)
- Rebooting to safe mode and back restores the driver function: this has worked every time I've done it, but is annoying to perform

These are all temporary work-arounds, but I'd like a more permanant solution. What type of a problem does this sound like, and what steps would you recommend I take to troubleshoot this? Let me know if there's additional information I can provide, and I'll update the question.

Update: I disabled Fast Boot, but this did not change anything

Comment: A permanent solution is to disable Fast Startup and avoid abusing suspension, i.e., as suggested, REBOOT some times. With the Fast Startup "feature" disabled it should work ALL the times after rebooting.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I disabled Fast Startup and the behaviour is the same as it was before, so I don't think that's what's causing the problem